# Relationship between the representation theory of $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ and $\operatorname{SO}(n)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}$What is the exact relationship between the finite dimensional representations of the group $\SO(n)$ and its covering group $\Spin(n)$? More precisely, what are examples of representations of $\Spin(n)$ that do not factor through a representation of $\SO(n)$? Can we give a complete description of such representations?

Comment: Obviously every rep of SO yields a rep of Spin by composition. And reps of Spin factor or don't factor (not "restrict") through reps of SO. Since there are faithful reps of Spin, there are reps of Spin that don't factors through reps of SO.

Comment: "Since both groups are different, they will have non-equivalent categories of representations" is *a priori* not true (depending on what you mean by 'different').  It doesn't make sense to talk about 'restriction' of representations in this setting, since there is no containment.  Instead, one can inflate representations of SO by pulling back to Spin, and not every representation of Spin arises this way—precisely those that are trivial on the relevant order-$2$ central subgroup. (I was writing this while @YCor commented; it's basically the same as their comment.)

Comment: @YCor, LSpice: I have edited based on your comments.

Comment: In general this boils down to irreducibles (a rep of Spin factors through SO iff all its irreducible subreps do). For $n=3$: $\mathrm{SU}(2)=\mathrm{Spin}(3)$ has one irreducible (complex) representation in each dimension $m\ge 1$, and those factoring through $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ are precisely those with $m$ odd.

Comment: @YCor: How does this extend to higher orders? Are the irreducibles of Spin(n) labelled by the weight lattice of SO(n) plus an extra $\mathbb{Z}$-parameter?

Comment: For $n=4$ it's a simple exercise: denote by $V_n$ the $n$-dim irreducible of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. Since $\mathrm{Spin}(4)=\mathrm{SU}(2)^2$, its irreducibles are $V_n\otimes V_m$ for $n,m\ge 1$, and such an irrep factors through $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ iff $n+m$ is even.

Comment: I suggest to check Prop 3.1.19 in "Symmetry, Representations, and Invariants" by Goodman and Wallach (Springer). In their notation, the set $P_{++}(G)$ parameterizing irreps of $G$ is explicitely described for $G=SO(2n)$ and $SO(2n+1)$ in terms of the fundamental representations $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n$. Of course, $P_{++}(\widetilde G)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z_{\geq0} \omega_i$ for $\widetilde G=Spin(2n)$ or $\widetilde G=Spin(2n+1)$ since $\widetilde G$ is simply connected.

Comment: That is, $P_{++}(SO(2n+1))=\mathbb Z_{\geq0} \omega_1 \oplus \dots \oplus Z_{\geq0} \omega_{n-1} \oplus Z_{\geq0} 2\omega_n$, and $P_{++}(SO(2n))=\mathbb Z_{\geq0} \omega_1 +\dots +\mathbb Z_{\geq0} \omega_{n-2} + \mathbb Z_{\geq0} 2\omega_{n-1} + \mathbb Z_{\geq0} 2\omega_n + \mathbb Z_{\geq0} (\omega_{n-1}+\omega_n)$.

Comment: @emiliocba: If you put this as an aswer then I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Irreducible representations of a simply connected semisimple Lie group $G$ are described by the coefficient of the highest weight on the fundamental weights, and they factor through a central quotient $G/C$ precisely when the highest weight belongs to the lattice $L$ (between the root lattice $Q$ and weight lattice $P$) associated with $G/C$ (in the sense that $P/L=C$ is the fundamental group, and $L/Q=Z(G/C)$ is the center).

Comment: (contd.) In the specific case where $G$ is Spin and $G/C$ is SO, this amounts to saying that the sum of the coefficients of the highest weight on the fundamental weights associated to the spin (for odd $n$) or half-spin (for even $n$) representations is even.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\def\Spin{\text{Spin}}$The cover $\Spin(n) \to SO(n)$ is $2$ to $1$, the nontrivial element kernel is a central element of $\Spin(n)$ which I'll call $z$. Since $z$ is central, it acts on any irrep of $\Spin(n)$ by $\pm 1$; if $z$ acts by $1$, then the irrep factors through $SO(n)$, if $z$ acts by $-1$, then it does not.

Irreps of Lie groups are usually described in terms of high weight vectors, which are characters of maximal tori. For notational simplicity, I'll take $n = 2m$ to be even. Then a maximal torus $T$ of $SO(2m)$ looks like
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \theta_1 & - \sin \theta_1 &&&&& \\
\sin \theta_1 & \cos \theta_1 &&&  \\
&& \cos \theta_2 & - \sin \theta_2 &&& \\
&& \sin \theta_2 & \cos \theta_2 &&& \\
&& && \ddots && \\
&&&&& \cos \theta_m & \sin \theta_m \\ 
&&&&& - \sin \theta_m & \cos \theta_m \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
so a character of $T$ looks like $e^{i (k_1 \theta_i+ \cdots + k_m \theta_m)}$ for some $(k_1, \ldots, k_m)$ in $\mathbb{Z}^m$. Such a character is dominant if $k_1 \geq k_2 \geq \cdots \geq k_{m-1} \geq |k_m|$. So irreps are indexed by $m$-tuples of integers $(k_1, \ldots, k_m)$ with $k_1 \geq k_2 \geq \cdots \geq k_{m-1} \geq |k_m|$.

Letting $\widehat{T}$ be a maximal torus for $\Spin(n)$, we have a short exact sequence
$$1 \to \langle z \rangle \longrightarrow \widehat{T} \longrightarrow T \to 1.$$
Characters of $\widehat{T}$ can be thought of as $m$-tuples $(k_1, \ldots, k_m)$ which lie in $\mathbb{Z}(1/2, 1/2, \ldots, 1/2) + \mathbb{Z}^m$, with the factors that have integer entries factoring through $T$ and the ones with half-integer entries not factoring. Again, a character is dominant if $k_1 \geq k_2 \geq \cdots \geq k_{m-1} \geq |k_m|$.

The simplest example of a representation of $\Spin(n)$ which doesn't factor through $SO(n)$ is the irrep with high weight $(1/2, 1/2, \ldots, 1/2)$; call it $W$. There isn't a simple description of this representation, but one thing that I find helpful is that there is a nonzero map $W \otimes W \longrightarrow \bigwedge^{m} \mathbb{R}^{2m}$. If you compute the matrices for $SO(2m)$ acting on $\bigwedge^{m} \mathbb{R}^{2m}$, you'll see that lots of the matrix entries are determinants of $m \times m$ skew symmetric matrices; the matrix entries for $W$ are the square roots of these determinants, meaning certain Pfaffians of $m \times m$ skew symmetric matrices.

There is no simple construction of $\Spin(n)$, but the usual route is by the Clifford algebra and can be found in books like Fulton and Harris's representation theory.